# Increment operators in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int a[5] = {5,1,15,20,25};
    int i,j,m;

    i = ++a[1];
    j = a[1]++;
    m = a[i++];

    printf("%d %d %d ",i,j,m);
}
```

The output of above program is:

> 3 2 15,

I just want to know why? I am having trouble in understanding increment operator.

Comment: use the statements of increment operators in printf...it will help you to understand...

Comment: People see `++` and immediately think "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, `a++` means first return `a`, then add `1` to `a`, while `++a` means first add `1` to `a`, then return `a`.

So

```
i = ++a[1];
j = a[1]++;
m = a[i++];
```

equals to

```
//i = ++a[1];
a[1] = a[1] + 1;//a[1] = 2
i = a[1];//i = 2
//j = a[1]++;
j = a[1];//j = 2
a[1] = a[1] + 1;//a[1] = 3
//m = a[i++];
m = a[i];//m = a[2] = 15
i = i + 1;//i = 3
```

So finally, i = 3, j = 2, m = 15.